# Need help deciding how to structure a C# application that creates products that share similarities but have their differences

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, interface, abstraction

I'm having a bit of a mental block trying to figure out the best architecture for this program and need some help.

I'm writing a C# application that creates what we'll call "Views".  A view is basically an object which accepts some data as input and spits out another object as output.

Here is the code I'm envisioning:

```
ViewResponse response;
ViewRequest request;

request = new CustomerViewRequest();
request.Translations = GetTranslations(); // generic to Request
request.CustomerViewAsOfDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1); // specific to CustomerViewRequest

response = ViewCreator.CreateView(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.ViewCreatedSuccessfully); // generic to Response
Console.WriteLine((CustomerViewResponse)response.SomeCustomerViewSpecificProperty); // specific to CustomerViewResponse

request = new BKLedgerViewRequest();
request.Translations = GetTranslations(); // generic to Request
request.EAAnalysisData = GetEAAnalysisData(); // specific to BKLedgerViewRequest

response = ViewCreator.CreateView(bkRequest);
Console.WriteLine(response.ViewCreatedSuccessfully); // generic to Response
Console.WriteLine((BKLedgerViewResponse)response.SomeBKLedgerViewSpecificProperty); // specific to BKLedgerViewResponse
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide some additional details if you want a useful response. I.e. Describing the purpose of a "View" and its "Request" / "Response" would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I look at your code, it seems like the key to accomplishing what you want is just to understand object-oriented coding, inheritance, covariance, and contravariance.  I did a re-factor of your code below that compiles and generally does what you are looking for based on using a base class for ViewRequest and ViewResponse.

When you instantiate the objects, using the more specific types of CustomerViewRequest (for example) gives you an object that you can treat as either a ViewRequest or a CustomerViewRequest, depending on your needs.

```
class Class6
{
    public object GetTranslations() { return null; }
    public object GetEAAnalysisData() { return null; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        CustomerViewRequest cvRequest = new CustomerViewRequest();
        cvRequest.Translations = GetTranslations(); // generic to Request
        cvRequest.CustomerViewAsOfDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1); // specific to CustomerViewRequest

        CustomerViewResponse cvResponse = ViewCreator.CreateViewResponse<CustomerViewResponse>(cvRequest);
        Console.WriteLine(cvResponse.ViewResponseCreatedSuccessfully); // generic to Response
        Console.WriteLine(cvResponse.SomeCustomerViewSpecificProperty); // specific to CustomerViewResponse

        BKLedgerViewRequest bkRequest = new BKLedgerViewRequest();
        bkRequest.Translations = GetTranslations(); // generic to Request
        bkRequest.EAAnalysisData = GetEAAnalysisData(); // specific to BKLedgerViewRequest

        BKLedgerViewResponse bkResponse = ViewCreator.CreateViewResponse<BKLedgerViewResponse>(bkRequest);
        Console.WriteLine(bkResponse.ViewResponseCreatedSuccessfully); // generic to Response
        Console.WriteLine(bkResponse.SomeBKLedgerViewSpecificProperty); // specific to BKLedgerViewResponse
    }
}

class ViewRequest
{
    public object Translations { get; set; }

}
class ViewResponse
{
    public bool ViewResponseCreatedSuccessfully { get; set; }
}
class CustomerViewRequest : ViewRequest
{
    public DateTime CustomerViewAsOfDate { get; set; }
}

class CustomerViewResponse : ViewResponse
{
    public string SomeCustomerViewSpecificProperty { get; set; }
}

static class ViewCreator
{
    public static T CreateViewResponse<T>(ViewRequest request)
        where T : ViewResponse, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
class BKLedgerViewResponse : ViewResponse
{
    public int SomeBKLedgerViewSpecificProperty { get; set; }
}

class BKLedgerViewRequest : ViewRequest
{
    public object EAAnalysisData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should never need *help* deciding on a Design Pattern.

The reason, a Design Pattern isn't meant to be a cookie cutter or a one pattern fits all.  A pattern should be implemented to solve a particular problem.  It shouldn't be used as raw architecture, but to help solve a particular issue.

Once you introduce a pattern, it will introduce complexity and limitations of its own.  Which may actually hinder your goal.

The real question should be, **how can I refactor this application to optimize performance, capture the application goal, and maintain readability / maintainability?**

Based on the information provided, we can't even recommend a pattern because we aren't aware of your applications goals, issues, and limitations.  This is why it is often up to the creator to find the optimal solution as you understand your application in a business, user, and developer manner.

Comment: thanks for your response. This is a brand new application so there is currently no codebase to refactor. I guess my question is more about deciding how to architect the application to make it readable and maintainable over the long run

Comment: @thiag0 Simplicity, you'll never code it perfect or correct.  Over time you'll learn cleaner and better approaches.